# I cannot modify a variable from a closure, why?

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, closures

I wanted to see if I can write some c# code in a javascript-fashion way but I got an unexpected behaviour. I know c# is not broken but I don´t understand what is wrong and why it doesn´t do what I think it should.

**Code**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = CreatePerson(new{
            FirstName = "Lucas",
            LastName = "Ontivero",
            Age = 34
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Name....... : {0}", person.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("IsJuvenile. : {0}", person.IsJuvenile);

        person.SetFirstName("Pablo");
        Console.WriteLine("Name....... : {0}", person.FullName);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static private dynamic CreatePerson(dynamic cfg)
    {
        string firstName = cfg.FirstName;
        string lastName = cfg.LastName;
        var age = cfg.Age;

        return new{
            FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName),
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
            SetFirstName = new Action<string>(fn => firstName= fn),
            SetLastName = new Action<string>(ln => lastName = ln),
            IsJuvenile = age < 18 
        };
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Name....... : Lucas Ontivero
IsJuvenile. : False
Name....... : Lucas Ontivero
```

**But I expected**:

```
Name....... : Lucas Ontivero
IsJuvenile. : False
Name....... : Pablo Ontivero
```

Why firstName doesn´t change?

Comment: Any way to get the code for the Person class?

Comment: @EtherDragon: There is no class, `CreatePerson` returns an instance of an anonymous type.

Comment: I think the key here is that you're returning an anonymous type, and anonymous types are always immutable. Nothing you do (with the possible exception of reflection hacks) will modify the values that you put into that anonymous type instance when you `new` it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does... but `FullName` does not.  It is computed inside `CreatePerson` and stored as a `string`, not a property evaluating to a string later.

You could use lambdas to cause delayed evaluation, as you did with `SetFirstName`.

Comment: Also, by setting `firstName`, is he setting the local variable `firstName` rather than the field `FirstName`?

Comment: @SirPentor: He's setting the captured variable `firstName` (variables used in a closure are not local).  And the field `FirstName` is a copy of `firstName` at the time the object is initialized.

Comment: @BenVoigt I need to learn about this new-fangled stuff in C#.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you fist assignment of FullName.
You need to re-assign FullName

```
FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName)
```

On `SetFirstName` Function